# How a site can tell whether a user inserted their own values in the URL

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am very curious because I would like to be able to check this myself on my own site, as I am currently in the process of designing it. An example would be:

www.somesite.com/product.php?id=1356

When using Facebook, a user can change it and they get the user associated with this id. But in other sites, specifically Ecommerce sites, when I change it, it either fails or goes to the homepage.

Comment: This is called the "get" method. Basically it's like a form when you "post" some information, but you have the data in the URL itself. You would get the information in PHP the same way as a form. If for example that ID doesn't exist, then you can redirect to the home page or unknown page. Facebook has many URLs, so the chances of hitting one is pretty easy.

Comment: Well I know that stuff, but there have been examples where the site definitely had that ID, and I checked myself, but when I put it in, it did not work. So I don't think its a simple validation.

Comment: you will need to post code then, because that's how it works. It's up to you how you want to handle the data that comes through. It doesn't just automatically happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way to see if the user changed it.  This is part of secure coding.  From the server's perspective, you need to validate all of your inputs, and validate that the current user actually should have access to the resource they're requesting.

See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4 for some additional details and examples.

Facebook may seem to allow this only for the example that you've given because the user profile ID that you're attempting to access may be public to you.  However, you won't have access to all other user profiles - only user profiles that you have permission to access.  If you tried to access my Facebook profile ID, you would also see your access be denied here.

Since this is tagged as e-commerce, you should also be aware of the [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) [DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?document=pci_dss_v2-0#pci_dss_v2-0) if you aren't already - where 6.5.4: "Insecure direct object references" applies specifically to this scenario.

Comment: I completely understand. But that means when I enter a valid ID for certain products on a site, it should work, but it doesn't. So I was just curious.

Comment: @Andy - please supply a specific example of where you've seen this; I'm curious.

Comment: I looked deeper into your link @ziesemer thank you very much. It kind gave me a good point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> When using Facebook, a user can change it and they get the user associated with this id. But in other sites, specifically Ecommerce sites, when I change it, it either fails or goes to the homepage.

Facebook does the same thing.

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=102934810293841029348 goes to an error page titled "Profile Unavailable", because that ID doesn't exist.

You're likely just changing it to nonexistent IDs.

Comment: Really? Because I was changing the user ID's in the URL and it worked just fine for me. Are you sure you are inputing just a few places ahead. I am not saying I am inputting arbitrary numbers. I know they exist due to me surfing the site.

Comment: It's possible they're checking HTTP_REFERER, but there's really no way to answer that without seeing examples. Ultimately, it'd be bad user experience in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

That works via $_GET method (or $_REQUEST)...

The reason you can change some site id (or any other parameter which is part of the url), and it works, is that because they programmed it to behave like that. It actually depends of how this url parameter is used in the background. For example, in product.php you will have something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) {
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $id = filterid(id)..... and so ...

  // Maybe check for id and redirect if id is not ok
  // Maybe check for id and some additional secrete parameter ...?

  // What is the id? What kind of behavior you want?
}
```

Reason why you have different behaviours across different websites - in dependence of url parameters (in this case "id") - is because different behaviours are implemented under different circumstances...

Some of them implement strict checks (especially for id's) because of the security!? For example, if you have page and you know that your id must be a number, and you know, that the max id in your database is for example 15000, you can write something like this....

```
if(isset($_GET['id'] && strlen($_GET['id']) <= 5 && isNumeric($_GET['id']) {
       //if everything is ok you can execute your code here
}
else {
      $id = 1; //if someone try to put something else in id, you will simply redirect him on first id(firs product)
}
```

That is just one example of behaviour. Now consider what else can be done? What do you want to do? How do you want it to behave? What kind of behaviour you will implement on your side - in dependencie of the parameters within the url is to totally up to you. **User can follow up your logic on your web app by clicking on your predefined links - or he can manipulate with the url how ever he wants. You dont have possibility to check this. All what you can do is properly validate all of the inputs (no matter are they coming from the URL or some kind of post request)**

Comment: Again, I checked to make sure the product ID existed, and it still did not work. But I understand what you mean. I just would like to understand how that works, because if there is no way to differentiate between user input and what you clicked, how are they figuring it out knowing that my user input is definitely valid, at least for their database?

Comment: You can somtime modify your code to work with your url....On what i mean with this.. For example you have <a href="?action=send_mail" >Something</a>.....when someone click on this link your url will be changed in....www.whatwasbefore.com?action=send_mail....IN THIS CASE with your $_GET method you can 100% check what is validate if you use like this if($_GET['action'] == send_mail) send_mail();

Comment: but if you are working with variables that will depend on, retrieving from database..you cannot be shure what is correct and what is not...user can input what ever he want...BUT YOU NEED TO MAKE SHURE THAT ONLY GOOD INPUTS GO IN DATABASE...(For example using PDO and prepare statements).....checking numeric..checking values...checking letter...regular expresions...and so

Comment: Yes, definitely. I appreciate the advice.